# WFFM Email Save Action - to: [Email], Sitecore adding extra brackets (Sitecore 6.5)

Tags: wffm

My client has a form where they want a confirmation email to be sent to the user on form submission, sent to whatever email address they specified in the Email field on the form. I set up a new Send Email Message save action and set the "To" field to [Email]

[image]

This works, however every time a content editor opens the Send Email Message editor, Sitecore is automatically adding extra brackets around Email:

To: [[Email]]

This breaks the form. I've informed my client to make sure to remove the extra brackets every time they save, but they're concerned about the form getting accidentally broken on production so I want to figure out why Sitecore is adding the extra brackets and how to stop it, or if there is a better way to send a confirmation message to the user based on a form field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know issue in Sitecore, reference number 402562.

In order to fix the error, you should download and apply the support fix for your version of WFFM (for Sitecore 6.5 it will be WFFM 2.3). You can find the fix in this Knowledge Base article: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/785584

Once you have downloaded the support patch, you should:

1. Put the `Sitecore.Support.402562.dll` file into the **\bin** folder.
2. Put the **SendEmail.xml** file into the **\sitecore\shell\Override folder**.
3. Reassign the value of a particular field using the Send Mail Editor dialog. This means you will have to edit any existing forms that have broken and remove the double brackets from these.
4. Publish the changes.